# How to catch and redirect not-found pages in a sub-directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have an existing site with a bunch of pages in `/widgets/` and the new site also has pages in `/widgets/`, some of which correspond to existing URLs. However, lots of other pages in that widgets section no longer exist and I just want to redirect them to `/widgets`.

Basically, I want to write a rule that catches pages that are not found and redirect them to the landing page (`/widgets/`) whilst allowing legit pages to be found.

Is it possible to write rules that will do this or do I need to manually redirect them all?

EDIT: As this is using a CMS (Craft) there are existing rules going on:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]`
```

Comment: If you are routing everything to `index.php` then how to figure out `not-existing-pages`?

Comment: I would assume 404's are handled entirely by the CMS - in the same way valid pages are handled (by checking the value of `p` in some database or other...?!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Since these pages only exist in the CMS itself and not as actual files on the filesystem then the CMS is also going to have to manage the redirection. Apache (.htaccess) does not know what is or is not a valid page, so unless you can determine a (filename) pattern to these redirects, you would need to specify each file/redirect manually in .htaccess.

---

Since this is an external redirect, it should come before your existing rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect non-existent files within /widgets/ to /widgets
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^widgets/. /widgets [R=301,L]

# Existing rewrites
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Note that the `RewriteRule` checks for the `/widgets/` directory, not `RewriteCond` directive - which would be less efficient.

I assume you already had a `RewriteBase` directive in your original code? This is required since you have a relative path substitution in your `RewriteRule`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working as it is still 404'ing on pages that don't exist :(

Comment: Ah, sorry, there should have been a redirect (`R=301` flag) on the `RewriteRule`. If it still doesn't work then what is it redirecting to? Is it redirecting at all?

Comment: with the 301 flag it is also redirecting legitimate requests

Comment: Ah, do these pages only exist within the CMS? ie. does `/widgets/path/to/valid/file` exist on the file system or only within your CMS? If it exists only within your CMS then I'm afraid you are going to have to do the redirection within your CMS as well, as Apache/.htaccess does not know whether the page exists or not. (I should have read my own comment at the top! *sigh*)

Comment: One way to do this is in your custom 404. Check the request path and redirect accordingly - the CMS might provide a wrapper for this? Otherwise, it's relatively trivial to do this in PHP.

Comment: I had a feeling this was the case. Seems like the only option.

Comment: If there is a filename-pattern to these non-existent files then you could still use .htaccess, or you could specify each redirect manually(!) - but otherwise there is no way to determine whether these pages actually exist in .htaccess.

Comment: Not sure whether I should mark this as the accepted answer, seeing as the real answer is in the comments!

Answer (score 1):

You can catch missing files in htaccess  with -f

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   // if not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   // if not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /widgets/(.*) // if in directory /widgets
RewriteRule ^.*$ /widgets [L]  // redirect to /widgets
```

You can leave out the third line if you want to redirect missing pages outside the widgets sub directory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I failed to mention that there's some existing rules that need to be taken into consideration—have edited my original post.